# SSL renegotion not allwowed

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, weblogic

I have an web app on a Weblogigc 12c server. It calls outside SOAP ws.  I am using SSL. I generated the client classes with Apache CXF.

I am receiving a SSLHandshakeException  Insecure renegotiation is not allowed.

What's weird is that even in the stack trace is gives the URL:  https://example.com:443/webservices/...  So it's calling the SSL port.

What's weirder is that my WS calls are all in a separate jar file for portability, and in Eclipse, I run a test class and all the calls work!

After some research, I can confirm the following:

I am using the same jdk1.8.0_31

I am using the same keystore

On Weblogic, I tried -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true and that changes the error to "no-renegotioation"

On Weblogic, I also added -Dsun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages=true but that also throws as "no-renegotioation" error

Any Ideas?

**UPDATE:**  I had the wrong weblogic version - it's 12 and reflected in the original post.  I have upgraded my JDK to 8.31

I do not see the Use JSSE SSL in the SSL advanced tab.

I turned on SSL logging and my client code does 2 things... : establishes a session, 2: makes a call. You can see in the log, that I am getting the first call working fine, a session ID is returned. But before the second call is even made, I get an error: here is the relevant bit:

```
%% Cached client session: [Session-5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 265
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 1054
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 906
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 21
Jan 28, 2015 1:38:22 PM com.mycompany.ws getNewWSSessionId
FINE: **** Setting sessionID in Context:b89bed7deed74d4a9283099e3d0518aa
******* Session established. SessionID:b89bed7deed74d4a9283099e3d0518aa
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', setSoTimeout(60000) called
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Insecure renegotiation is not allowed
%% Invalidated:  [Session-5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 18
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', called closeSocket()
```

The the exception is thrown from Apache CXF:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
at  org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
at   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.loginTool(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I believe that version of Weblogic still supports both the Certicom and JSSE SSL implementations.  This is only a guess but I would check to see if the weblogic server has "use JSSE" turned on or not (it is in the Weblogic admin console Environment->servers->your server->SSL tab->advanced link->bottom of the page) and then restart/retry.

Comment: Can you post the client code you're using? Something is wrong with how you're connecting/using sockets

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. any help?